# I cannot see a complete date label in my time series plot, only months

Tags: r, date, plot, time-series

I have the following code to plot data:

```
data$Date = as.POSIXct(strptime(data$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d"))

plot(data$Date, risk_port, type = "b", col = "blue", main = "Portfolio vs Benchmark", xlab = "Date", ylab = "Risk", panel.first = grid(),lwd = 2)
lines(data$Date, risk_bmk, type = "b", col = "red",lwd = 2)
```

where,

```
str(data)
tibble [12 x 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Date: POSIXct[1:12], format: "2019-08-30" "2019-09-30" "2019-11-29" "2019-12-31" ...
```

but the plot I get has only months..

[image]
the labels are: Sept, Nov, Jan and so on,
no year, no day.

I attach the dput below:

```
dput(data)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1567123200, 1569801600, 1574985600, 
1577750400, 1580428800, 1582848000, 1585612800, 1588204800, 1590710400, 
1593475200, 1596153600, 1598832000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Can anybody help please? I am really wasting lot of time on this

Many thanks

Luigi

Comment: Can you edit the question with the output of `dput(data)`? Without the actual data it's difficult to say what's going on.

Comment: yes, just did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways, the first a base R solution and the second a `tidyverse/ggplot2` one.

First of all, I will make up the two variables to be plotted, since they weren't posted.

```
risk_port <- seq_len(nrow(data))
risk_bmk <- 0.5*risk_port
```

Now the base R solution. Create a vector of labels one month apart from one another. Then plot with `xaxt = "n"` in order to suppress the x axis and plot it manually.

```
labs <- seq(min(data$Date), max(data$Date), by = "month")
plot(data$Date, risk_port, type = "b", col = "blue",
     main = "Portfolio vs Benchmark", 
     xlab = "Date", ylab = "Risk", 
     panel.first = grid(),lwd = 2,
     xaxt = "n")
axis(1, at = labs, labels = format(labs, "%b-%Y"))
lines(data$Date, risk_bmk, type = "b", col = "red",lwd = 2)
```

[image]

Second, the `ggplot2` solution. Create a data set with the two extra columns, reshape to long format, get rid of the `"risk_"`

```
data %>%
  mutate(risk_port = risk_port, risk_bmk = risk_bmk) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Date, names_to = 'type', values_to = 'risk') %>%
  mutate(type = sub("risk_", "", type)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date, risk, color = type)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]